# `$state.go` doesn't pass value to `$stateParams`

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an angular code in componentA

```
$state.go('home', {selectedFilter: "no_filter"});
```

and this code in componentB

```
if ($stateParams.selectedFilter === 'no_filter')
```

But i still get `$stateParams.selectedFilter as undefined`

what am i missing?

Comment: Have you include `selectedFilter` in the path `url: "my-page/search?selectedFilter"` (For example)? You can also use the `params` for this

Comment: @AlonEitan, I think it's not needed to include `selectedFilter`.

Comment: @Hadi Please [read this](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing): _**Note:** `$stateParams` service must be specified as a state controller, and it will be scoped so **only the relevant parameters defined in that state** are available on the service object._

Comment: @AlonEitan You are right:) thanks for shared the link :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can use $stateParams.selectedFilter

only if i define selectedFilter in the app

```
        $stateProvider.state('home', {
            url: '/',
            template: '<home-component></home-component>',
            component: 'homeComponent',
            params: {
                selectedFilter: undefined
            }
        })
```